# amsmath is loaded but "\end{aligned}" is undefined control sequence

Tags: align, amsmath, overleaf

Here is the MWE (using XeLateX on overleaf):

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, preprint]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, graphicx, outline, float, cite, color}
\usepackage{longtable,array}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{S\arabic{table}}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{font=footnotesize,labelfont=normalsize}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {Figs/} }
\newcommand{\tcr} { \textcolor{red} }

\title{compile errors}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    \bm{K} &= \sigma_0\\
    \text{foo} &= \text{bar}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Here is the full error output:

```
<argument>  \bm 
                {K}(\bm {x},\bm {x'}) &= \sigma _0 + \sigma _i^2 exp 
\left [...
l.383 \end{align}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Comment: Unrelated to your error but you have `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` so this document should be used with pdflatex. Never use those packages with xelatex.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.  I switched it back to pdflatex and everything works.  It would be nice if such configurations could be specified in a tracked config file, then I'd have some idea why we had XeLateX on in the first place!

Comment: Also, don't load the same package twice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You did not show the error mesage which is:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument>  \bm 
                {K} &= \sigma _0\\ \text {foo} &= \text {bar} 
l.25 \end{align}

?
```

So this is showing you that the undefined command is `\bm` for which you need to load the `bm` package.

Comment: Thanks for catching this!  I added bm to the includes and everything is working.  I updated the original post to include the complete error output.

Comment: I think I just scanned the message and stopped reading when I saw "l.383", thinking 'ok we have an issue on line 383', haha

Comment: @mkk that tells you how much of the file tex had read before it found the error but it always grabs the whole of an ams alignment before evaluating it so any error is reported at the end of the environment